# docker compose linking container network

Tags: node.js, docker-compose

I have two containers, one for the database (DynamoDBLocal) and the other for the web app written in Nodejs.  I use Docker compose to setup the two containers and this is what my compose file looks like.

version: '2'

```
services:
  DynamoDBLocal:
    container_name: DynamoDBLocal
    build:
      context: ./DynamoDBLocal
    image: tag/drive-sync/dynamodb:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  SetupService:
    build:
      context: ./setup
    image: tag/drive-sync/setup_service:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

My Nodejs app speaks to the DynamoDBLocal container.  As I understand both the containers get created under the same network as per the new Docker and when I try to access the DynamoDBLocal DB from the Nodejs App using the following url

http://DynamoDBLocal:8000  I get the following error

"message": "Inaccessible host: `dynamodblocal'. This service may not be available in the`us-west-2' region.",

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#linking-containers-in-user-defined-networks) when they say that the  "supports the --link option to provide name alias for the linked container" I assume that you should be using the `links` option in your compose file to get name aliasing.

```
SetupService:
build:
  context: ./setup
image: tag/drive-sync/setup_service:latest
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
links:
  - "DynamoDBLocal:dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
```